# Multiple <HTTP> tags with entry-point-ref and authentication-manager-ref tags

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

I know this question has been asked a couple of times before but I somehow am not able to crack it. Help would really be appreciated, as I am stuck on it for a while.

My security XML appended below has been working file for a while, but it is needed that I add another  tag to include WebService Security

Existing Security XML

```
    <security:http pattern="/abc.html" security="none"/>
<security:http pattern="/dev.html" security="none"/>

<security:http entry-point-ref="authenticaionEntryPoint">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/*.xyz" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/login_failure.do" />
    <security:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="customAuthenticationFilter"/>
    <security:anonymous username="guest" granted-authority="ROLE_ANONIM"/>
</security:http>

<bean id="authenticaionEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login.jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="customAuthenticationFilter" class="package.security.CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
            <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/login_success.jsp" />
            <property name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl" value="false" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
            <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login_failure.do" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationProvider" class="package.security.CustomAuthenticationProvider" />

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider"/>        
</security:authentication-manager>
```

I need to add

```
    <security:http pattern="/SetWebServices*" create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="remotingAuthenticationManager" auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/SetWebServices*" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    <security:http-basic/> 
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager  alias="remotingAuthenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="adminuser" password="adminpass" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Both of them work separately but putting second piece on top gives 403 Access denied on /SetWebServices?WSDL.

Any help/direction/inputs would be really appreciated.

Comment: Figured that out. Last Authentication Manager was Used. Used Id instead of alias - Resolved the issue.

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1937
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?123956-Multiple-authentication-managers-Defined-But-Only-the-Last-One-Is-Applied